# How to filter and copy files in Azure Data Factory without using loop over pipeline parameters?

Tags: loops, filter, copy, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I want to copy files in a Container in an Azure blob storage which contains around 10,000,000 files.

Filename format looks like "Energy_ReportName_Timestamp_VersionNumber.zip". The sample filename could be "Energy_Payment_20231209110007_0000000404988124.zip". VersionNumber at the end of the filename doesn't have a regular pattern.

All files are located in the source container and there is no sub-folder or nested folders.

I want to filter zip files for a specific **ReportName** from **StartDate** until **EndDate**, and copy those files to the destination container. The filters are applied to the filename. Also, the filename must start with "Energy".

For example, files for "ReportName" = Payment; and StartDate = 20231101 (at any time on this date and any VersionNumber) and EndDate = 20231205.

Sample acceptable filenames:

- Energy_Payment_20231101110007_0000000404988124.zip
- Energy_Payment_20231102110007_0000000404988124.zip
- Energy_Payment_20231103110007_0000000404988124.zip
- Energy_Payment_20231203110007_0000000404988124.zip

Since there are millions of files in the source container, I am looking for an approach that is fast to find the desired files and copy them to the sink container using the Copy activity in Azur eData Factory.

I want to avoid using a loop over every date since it makes it slow to filter files for one day (due to having a large number of files in the container), copy files, and then repeat the process for the next days.

Also, I tried the "Get Metadata" activity to get a list of files but it failed due to the large number of files in the container with below message:

```
The length of execution output is over limit (around 4MB currently)
```

Is there any way that I can filter or select all desired files (from StartDate to EndDate), and copy them in one run?

Answer (score 1):

These are the files in my input container named  `inputdata`.

```
Energy_Payment_20231209110007_0000000404988124.zip
Source_Payment_20231209010215_0000000404982426.zip
Employee_Payment_20231209122424_00000004049171224.zip
Business_Cash_20231209101602_0000000404988124.zip
Fund_Payment_20231208161001_0000000404988124.zip
```

Create pipeline parameters for Startdate, EndData and ReportName

[image]

In copy activity of ADF pipeline, take binary source and binary target dataset. In the source and sink dataset, give the path till the container name.

[image]

Similarly, give the path till the target container in the target binary dataset.

Now, give the source dataset to copy activity source and give the wild card file name  `*@{pipeline().parameters.ReportName}_@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.StartDate,'yyyyMMdd')}*.zip`  And start date and End date to **filter by last modified** the files like below.

[image]

Now run the pipeline, you can see the required files will get copied to the target location like below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The "Last modified" property of the files is not necessarily the timestamp in the filename. Could you please share a screenshot of the source container in your test? I'd like to see the "Modified" column for the source files. I am looking for a way to filter based on the filename from StartDate to EndDate.

Comment: Is it possible to construct a filter in the "Wildcard file path" that covers a range of dates from StartDate to EndDate? If there is any function like DateRange, Between, ... in ADF?

Comment: there is no such function to create filter on files names with date range.